# Can I use addEventListener('play') inside a function? the function is running but the addeventlistener('play') is not

Tags: javascript

```
const faceDetection = () => {
      const video = document.getElementById(`video`);
      console.log(video);
    
      const displaySize = { width: video.width, height: video.height };
    
      video.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log(`run`);
      });
    
      video.addEventListener('play', () => {
        console.log(`run`);
        const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video);
        camera.append(canvas);
    
        faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize);
    
        // interval
        setInterval(async () => {
          console.log(`this run`);
    
          const detections = await faceapi
            .detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions())
            .withFaceLandmarks();
    
          const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize);
    
          canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
          faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections);
    
          faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections);
        }, 100);
      });
    };
```

the video.addEventListener('click') does run but video.addEventListener('play') does not, can someone please give me idea why does it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake I did call the vid.play(); on the navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia();

```
navigator.mediaDevices
.getUserMedia({ video: true })
.then((stream) => {
  vid.srcObject = stream;
  // vid.play();
  if (backend === 'webgl') return faceDetection(100);
  if (backend === 'cpu') return faceDetection(1000);
  track = stream.getTracks();
  resetMessages();
})
.catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
})
.finally(() => {
  preloader.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe your component may not be loaded yet when you call the function, can you try to make a timeout ?
Like in is issue :
[Stackoverflow - How can i make a waitFor(delay)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56285655/how-can-i-make-a-waitfordelay-function-in-javascript-inside-a-loop)